# Splash screen related in iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, animation, splash-screen, ios-3.x

Hi I am trying to splash screen with the help of timer. but it can't. IS any suggestion regarding this code.........

**SplashViewController.h:-**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "MainMenu.h"

@interface SplashViewController : UIViewController {
    UIImage *imgSplash;
    NSTimer *timer;
    MainMenu *objMainMenuView;
}

@property (nonatomic,retain) NSTimer *timer;
@property (nonatomic,retain) UIImage *imgSplash;
@property (nonatomic,retain) MainMenu *objMainMenuView;



@end
```

**SplashViewController.m:-**

```
#import "SplashViewController.h"


@implementation SplashViewController
@synthesize timer,imgSplash,objMainMenuView;

// Implement viewDidLoad to do additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    timer = [[NSTimer alloc] init]; 

    UIImageView *splashImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,320,460)];
    imgSplash = [[UIImage alloc] init];
    imgSplash = [UIImage imageNamed:@"chicocredit_splash.png"];
    [splashImageView setImage:imgSplash];

    [self.view addSubview:splashImageView];

    timer = [NSTimer timerWithTimeInterval:2.0 target:self.timer selector:@selector(fadeScreen) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
    if([timer isValid]==1)
    {       
        [timer fire];
        //self.view.alpha = 0.0;

        objMainMenuView = [[MainMenu alloc] initWithNibName:@"MainMenu" bundle:nil];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:objMainMenuView animated:YES];
    }   
}

-(void) onTimer{
    NSLog(@"LOAD");
}

- (void)fadeScreen
{


    [UIImageView beginAnimations:nil context:nil]; 
    [UIImageView setAnimationDuration:2.0];       
    [UIImageView setAnimationDelegate:self];
    [UIImageView commitAnimations];

    //[UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector:@selector(finishedFading)];  

    //self.view.alpha = 0.0;       
    //[UIView commitAnimations];   
}

/*
- (void) finishedFading
{   
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil]; 
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:5.0];

    //self.view.alpha = 1.0;   
    //viewController.view.alpha = 1.0;
    //self.objMainMenuView.view.alpha = 1.0;

    [UIView commitAnimations];   
    //[splashImageView removeFromSuperview];
}*/




- (void)dealloc {
    [super dealloc];
}


@end
```

Comment: You have just single image so its not necessary to take animation so use just time delay i put your solution in below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this It may be solution for that.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

timer = [[NSTimer alloc] init]; 


CGRect myImageRect = CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 320.0f, 460.0f);
splashImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:myImageRect]; 
[splashImageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image3.jpg"]];
splashImageView.opaque = YES; 
[self.view addSubview:splashImageView];
[splashImageView release]; 

[self performSelector:@selector(doTHis) withObject:nil afterDelay:2.0];
[super viewDidLoad];
```

}

```
-(void)doTHis{
objMainMenuView = [[MainMenu alloc] initWithNibName:@"MainMenu" bundle:nil];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:objMainMenuView animated:YES];
```

}

Good Luck

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your MianMenu is getting pushed before you can see the fade effect. Its because you are firing the timer and pushing the Main Menu immediately.

// Schedule the timer here.

```
[NSTimer timerWithTimeInterval:2.0f target:self selector:@selector(timerFireMethod:) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
```

// Timer fire method.

```
-(void) timerFireMethod:(NSTimer *) theTimer {
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context: nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:2.0f];
[UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
[UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector: @selector(animationDidStop: finished: context:)];

// Put animation code.

[UIView commitAnimations];
```

}

// Called when animation finishes.

```
-(void) animationDidStop:(NSString *)animationID finished:(NSNumber *)finished context:(void *)context {
// Called when animation finishes.
// Push the Main menu here.
}
```

Keep break point in the timer fire method. It should get called after 2 seconds as specified.
Then keep break point in the animationDidStopSelector method. It will get called after your fade animation of 2 seconds.

Comment: Thanx but i tried still it's not working plz give me some suggestion.

Comment: Can you tell us the behavior? Does it fade? Does it pushes to Main Menu without fading? And Immediately?

Answer (score 0):

Your code is leaked:

1:

```
timer = [[NSTimer alloc] init]; //Leak here, remove this line
.
.
.
timer = [NSTimer timerWithTimeInterval:2.0 target:self.timer selector:@selector(fadeScreen) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
```

2:

```
imgSplash = [[UIImage alloc] init];//Leak here, remove this line
imgSplash = [UIImage imageNamed:@"chicocredit_splash.png"];
```

3:

```
   UIImageView *splashImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,320,460)];
    ...
    [splashImageView setImage:imgSplash]; //Leak here, should release splashImageView
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not, do everything else after timer expired and fading is done.

```
- (void) finishedFading
{   
        objMainMenuView = [[MainMenu alloc] initWithNibName:@"MainMenu" bundle:nil];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:objMainMenuView animated:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

short cut: use another viewController with imageView present it modally and dismiss with animation dissolve.
You should present view in viewWillAppear.Start timer on viewLoad of second viewController.When timer fires dismiss it.